# Building A Dependency List with GCC and Make

Tags: makefile

There appear to be multiple weird ways to do this, and it combines a lot of things in make that I don't quite understand. My folder structure is as follows.

```
src
  | - utils
    | - utils.h
    | - utils.c
    | - buffer.c
    | - json.c
  | - middleware
    | - middleware.h
    | - middleware.c
  | - server
    | - etc
tests
  | - utils.c
  | - middleware.c
  | - server.c
```

Every folder under `src` is a library. and all files under that folder comprise the library.

For every library there is a respective `.c` file, under the `tests` dir, which will become an executable that can run each of those tests.

Any library can depend on other libraries, so I want to ensure that with make, when I make a change, the dependency tree is rebuilt, and each library retested that has a modification in a dependent file.

Here is what I have tried. I am leaving out quite obvious or irrelevant things for brevity.

```
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*/*.c))
INCS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.h,$(INCDIR)/%.h,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*/*.h))
IMMM := $(patsubst $(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(LIBDIR)/%.a,$(foreach LIB,$(LLIST),$(filter $(OBJDIR)/$(LIB)/$(LIB).o,$(OBJS))))
LIBS := $(foreach PRE,$(LLIST),$(subst $(PRE)/,lib,$(filter $(LIBDIR)/$(PRE)/$(PRE).a,$(IMMM))))
LINK := $(foreach LIB,$(LLIST),-l$(LIB))
TSTO := $(patsubst $(TSTDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/$(TSTDIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(TSTDIR)/*.c))
TSTE := $(foreach LIB,$(LLIST),$(TGTDIR)/$(LIB).exe)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)
DEPT := $(TSTO:.o=.d)

.PHONY: all 
all: $(TGTDIR)/$(TGT)

$(TGTDIR)/$(TGT): $(LIBS) | tests
    $(CC) -o $@ bench/main.c $(LIBS) 

tests: $(TSTE)
    for test in $^ ; do \
        chmod +x ./$${test} ; \
        ./$${test}; \
    done
    
$(TSTE): $(TSTO) $(DEPT) | $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(filter $(OBJDIR)/$(TSTDIR)/$(basename $(notdir $@)).o, $(TSTO))

$(OBJDIR)/$(TSTDIR)/%.o: $(TSTDIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/$(TSTDIR)/%.d: $(TSTDIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -MM -MG $< $(CFLAGS)

$(LIBS): $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $(filter $(subst lib,$(OBJDIR)/, $(basename $(notdir $@)))/%.o, $(OBJS))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | folders
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | folders
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -MM -MG $< $(CFLAGS)
```

The output for deps and dept are:

```
deps => obj/middleware/middleware.d obj/utils/utils.d
dept => obj/tests/middleware.d obj/tests/utils.d
```

All of the test dependencies are getting listed correctly.
`gcc -MM -MG tests/middleware.c -Wall -O0 -std=c11 -DDEBUG -g` outputs

```
middleware.o: tests/middleware.c tests/../src/middleware/middleware.h
```

However, I don't see the bug, why my `$(OBJDIR)/%.d` `$(DEPS) dependencies are not being ran.

So,

1. I'm not sure what `sed` command I need to get the desired output from `(CC) -MM -MG $< $(CFLAGS)`
2. Do I need the `-include: $(DEPS)` and `-include: $(DEPT) where does that go?
3. Where is the bug not allowing $(DEPS) target to run?
4. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You have two source files named `middleware.c`, you want to build `$(OBJDIR)/middleware.o` and `$(OBJDIR)/$(TSTDIR)/middleware.o`, and you are constructing lists of prerequisites for `middleware.o`. Do yourself a big favor and name the test source `test_middleware.c`.

Comment: @Beta I'm not sure how that's the issue. Without the dependencies targets/recipes, it works just fine for the libraries. The output for the `gcc -MM -MG` command looks correct as well. `middleware.o` which is `tests/middleware.c` has a dependency on itself, and `src/middleware/middleware.h` which is correct. Are you saying the `sed` command would be difficult to construct?

Comment: As far as I understand nothing depends on your `$(OBJDIR)/%.d` files and you do not include them. So, why do you think they should be built? A visit to this [excellent blog post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) could help, I think. You can take the `TL;DR:` tour if you are in a hurry but the full read will probably learn you a lot of things about GNU make and auto-dependency generation.

Comment: Why do you have `$(DEPT)` in the prerequisites of the executables? `.d` files only handle dependencies between object files and their sources.